# User selects multiple items using check_box form helper; POSTs data as array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox, form-helpers

Trying to convert a form where previously only one option could be selected from multiple items using radio_button, to a form where multiple options can be selected using check_box.

Original code:

```
 <% @inventory.each do |category, list| %>
   <div class="col-xs-3">
     <div class="form-group box">
        <h5> <%="#{category.upcase}"%> </h5>
             <% list.each do |thing| %>
             <%= f.radio_button(:item, "#{thing}") %>
             <%= f.label(:item, "#{thing}") %>
             </br>
             <% end %>
     </div>
  </div>  
 <% end %>
```

If all the nested each|dos seem confusing, basically what's happening is there are multiple categories of items being generated from an inventory hash. Each category looks distinct on the form, but a radio_button check on any item in any category counts as the one item you're selecting.

The class is "Request" and the column that this data posts to is "Item":

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :item, presence: true
```

I need to now make it so that a user can check any item in any category, and all of those items are POSTed as an array. I tried replacing the radio_button line with:

```
<%= f.check_box(:item, {:multiple => true}, "#{thing}") %>
```

It seems as though it's working, since I just tested and the Rails debugger shows the following:

```
request: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
  item:
  - '0'
  - '0'
  - Sleeping bag
  - '0'
  - Sleeping pad
```

However when I click the submit button, I get the error message that "Item cannot be blank."

Help?

EDIT: add controller code:

```
  def new
    @requestrecord = Request.new
    inventory #This calls a private method that lists all the items by category and list
    @pagetitle = "What would you like to borrow?"
  end

  def create
    @requestrecord = Request.new(request_params)
    inventory
    @pagetitle = "What would you like to borrow?"

    if @requestrecord.save
      flash[:success] = "Thanks, we'll respond in a few hours. Below is the information you submitted in case you need to change anything."
      @requestrecord.save_spreadsheet
      RequestMailer.confirmation_email(@requestrecord).deliver
      redirect_to edit_request_path(@requestrecord.edit_id)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def request_params
      params.require(:request).permit(:email, :item, :detail, :rentdate, :edit_id)
    end
```

Comment: Can you show us the controller code for your form action?

Comment: Just added the controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a typical mistake when handling array type of form parameters and strong parameters.

You need to tell the controller that it's ok to accept an array of "items".

So, change your definition of `request_params` liike this:

```
def request_params
    params.require(:request).permit(:email, {:item => []}, :detail, :rentdate, :edit_id)
end
```

And it should be over with this error.

Comment: I also had to add `serialize :item` in the model, but this worked great thanks!

Comment: @james, Could you provide an example?

Comment: Yeah so the other thing to note as I'm sure you'll read if you poke around is that serialization isn't ideal, you should make another associated table. But if you need to do it, use the params syntax as above, and then in the model for whatever is accepting the array, write `serialize :items`, the attribute you want to serialize.